# how to generate a number following a pattern using sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to generate a pattern in SQL Server.

e.g. PA0001

and increment it every time (meaning if PA0001 has already been generated the next should be PA0002 and so on).

I have no idea how to go about this!

Can anyone help?

Comment: Is the prefix always `'PA'`?

Comment: the pattern as a matter of fact is a bit more complex than that! it's PA+"CURRENTDATE"+"01, so for each day they numeric part will reset,

Comment: Downvote reason: Why don't you ask about the real pattern you need then? People are wasting their time answering an irrelevant question.

Answer (score 0):

The canonical way is to have an indentity column and then create this code as a computed column:

```
create table . . . (
    inc int not null identity(1, 1),
    . . .
    code as ('PA' + right('0000' + cast(inc as varchar(255)), 4)
```

This only works with one prefix -- if you want all values to start with 0001.  If you have multiple prefixes, you can:

- Use a trigger.
- Calculate the code in queries.
- Change your requirements so you can use codes that do not have other meanings.

Comment: can this be done in a function rather than in a table?

Answer (score 0):

You can write as:

```
create table Test
(
    ID int identity not null primary key,
    pattern  varchar(100)
)

Go

create function Nextpattern (@id int) 
returns varchar(20) 
as 
begin 
return 'PA' + 
 CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 110) + right('00' + convert(varchar(10), @id), 2) 
end

--Solution 1:
Go

alter table Test add Newpattern as dbo.Nextpattern(ID)

Go

insert into Test values (1)

Go


--solution2:
-- not good as what if two processes attempt to 
-- add a row to the table at the exact same time?
create function dbo.fnNextpattern() 
returns varchar(20) 
as 
begin 
    declare @lastval varchar(20) 
    set @lastval = (select max(pattern) from Test) 
    if @lastval is null set @lastval = 'PA' + 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 110) + '01'
    declare @i int 
    set @i = right(@lastval,2) + 1 
    return 'PA' +
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 110)+ right('00' + convert(varchar(10),@i),2) 
end
go
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/77c44/1)</kbd>